# Logging using Log4j NDC

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

I have a java program in which I call multiple threads.What I want is while logging I need a unique Id representing the whole program ie ,This unique Id should be involved in all the log statements of the threads also.

Right now I am using log4j NDC.But , the problem is that in log statements of the thread the unique Id which I pushed in the "main" is not getting printed (as it is a separate thread). What can I do so that I can have this unique Id in all the logs of the threads.I do not want to changes all the log statements of the thread.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the thread id/name in log for each thread.

Comment: Can you post more details ie. logger statement and more